# How do the server distinguish whether it is a robot or a human when using selenium webdriver to crawl web pages?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-crawler

Our lab has cooperation with a web company, it has developed technology that can protect web pages from being crawled by web-crawler.The testing website is http://119.254.209.77/ .I can't get urls on the page of left part such as "Checking". It will create a url just when I click the link.With **Python+Selenium+Firefox**, I simulated the click operation, but I **got a blank page** rather than the real data.If I just click the link myself, it will return real data.So I want to know how the server can  identify i'm a web crawler when I use selenium webdriver with firefox? Also I want to know **how to aviod being treated as a web crawler** by it's website.

here is my code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://119.254.209.77/')
    time.sleep(5)
    pageSource = driver.page_source
    print(driver.page_source)

    # the target url

    checking = driver.find_element_by_id('_ctl0__ctl0_Content_MenuHyperLink2')

    # it seems to has no effects
    checking.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because of some reason, I wan't to delete the post.What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the site is checking to see where you're mouse is before passing you to the next page. Moving to the element before clicking it works for me:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://119.254.209.77/')
time.sleep(5)
pageSource = driver.page_source
print(driver.page_source)
# the target url
checking = driver.find_element_by_id('_ctl0__ctl0_Content_MenuHyperLink2')

action_chain = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action_chain.move_to_element(checking)
action_chain.click(checking)
action_chain.perform()
time.sleep(2)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Well, on firefox sometimes it doesn't work even if I click it myself. It might just not work on firefox.